# Is ubuntu AMI is slower than windows AMI on AWS

Tags: ubuntu, browser, amazon-ec2

I am using two instance, one of ubuntu and other of windows with same configuration. Ubuntu instance takes more time than windows instance for each action on browser. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Funny question, doubt you will get any interesting response here, because it's not a coding question

Answer (score 0):

The performance and Network depends on Region as well